# How do I create an ODBC connection to OracleXE using sp_addlinkedserver in MSSQL using a DSN-LESS connection string?

Tags: oracle, odbc, linked-server

How do I create an ODBC connection using sp_addlinkedserver in SQL using a DSN-LESS connection string?

I assume I am doing something wrong with syntax, here is how I set up the connection:

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'SERVER_NAME', 
@srvproduct=N'Oracle', 
@provider=N'MSDASQL', 
@provstr=N'DataSource=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVER_NAME)(PORT=INSTANCE_PORT)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))'
GO

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you validated the connection string separately to ensure it is working?

Comment: Yes the connection string works with a DSN specified.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) you should be using `@provider=N'MSDAORA'`
You might also need to use `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` in order to successfully login to your ORA server.

Have you checked [this](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/07/16/linked-servers-in-sql-server/) out?

By the way, you can check the connection like it is shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/07/426578.aspx), but first of all make sure you do have a linked server after you run `sp_addlinkedserver` using this select: `SELECT * FROM sys.syservers`

Make sure you delete the linked server after you're done with it.

Are you linking the Oracle server in the same query with the select? Because this might not work successfully.